# Different output in Leetcode IDE and Vscode

Tags: javascript

443.String Compression -
I practiced this problem in VSCode before copying it to the LeetCode IDE. However, for some reason, the output results on LeetCode were different. Did I miss something?

[image]

```js
/**
 * @param {character[]} chars
 * @return {number}
 */
var compress = function (chars) {
    let arr = [];
    let times = 0;
    let current = chars[0];
    while (chars.length > 0) {
        let last = chars.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            if (chars[i] === current) {
                times++;
            }
        }
        chars = chars.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
            return value !== current;
        });
        arr.push(current);
        times > 1 && arr.push(...(times + ''));
        times = 0;
        current = chars[0];
    }
    chars = arr;
    console.log(chars, chars.length);
    return chars.length;
};
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Why are you returning a number when it expects the output to be an array? How are you testing it in VSCode?

Comment: @vr. The last line of the problem description says "After you are done modifying the input array, return the new length of the array." Why do you think the return value should be an array?

Comment: You're supposed to modify `char` in place. Assigning `char = arr` doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: You're also ignoring the requirement that the length of each group should be less than 10.

Comment: @Barmar I used ```arr.push(...(times + ''))``` to expand string for bigger than 10, is it undesirablet?

Comment: Now I'm not sure. The instructions say "Note that group lengths that are 10 or longer will be split into multiple characters in `chars`". I thought it was talking about the result, but now I see that it's talking about the input.

Comment: The description is a little difficult to understand. I think I'll practice other problems first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the array `chars` in-place. Assigning to `chars` only changes the parameter value inside the function, but does not change the original array.

Remove the line `chars = arr;`. Instead, you can use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to replace the array.

```js
chars.splice(0, chars.length, ...arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your modification, which let me know that this approach is feasible. Unfortunately, the submission result was the same. It seems that someone had a similar situation in the Leetcode comments section in recent days. I will try to submit again in a few days.

Comment: @miyen Are you certain that the rest of your code is correct then? This should fix the issue of propagating changes to the array back, but your algorithm must also be correct for it to work.

Comment: @miyen I see there's another issue; you're changing `chars` in `chars = chars.filter(...)`. You should store that in another variable and refrain from changing `chars` at all until the end. Otherwise you lose the reference to the array that you need to change.